# Cytoscape with expand collapse extension in react throws an error

Tags: reactjs, cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape.js in react and cytoscape.js-expand-collapse. I register this extension at the very begining of my file as shown in docs: https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-expand-collapse: by doing expandCollapse( cytoscape ); and it works only on first render. When I come back to my cytoscape component I receive following error: Can not register `expandCollapse` for `core` since `expandCollapse` already exists in the prototype and can not be overridden. So my question is- has anyone had similar problem with using this extension in react and know how to deal with it?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The library is just saying that it is already registered on the core. Giving an if condition will solve this problem:

```
    if (typeof cytoscape('core', 'expandCollapse') == 'undefined') {
      cytoscape.use(require('cytoscape-expand-collapse'));
    }
```

When we load, react will unmount and remount the component which will cause it initialize everything again, in here the 3rd party libraries. I have used the same if code for other cytoscape libraries when we reload and it works.